# Infinite with angular services and interceptor

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-http, angular7, angular-http-interceptors

I am working in an e-commerce using angular 6 and i'm having the following issue.

I'm using an interceptor to set a custom header to the requests. This custom header is a hash stored in LocalStorage and is provided by the CartService.

I also have an AuthService with an observable that emits whether the user is logged or not.

In the CartService, it receives the AuthService using dependency injection and subscribe to that observable to see if user is logged in or not, and reload the cart from back-end whenever the user logs in or out.

The problem is: When i inject the CartService in the interceptor, an infinite loop occurs, because the constructor of CartService runs again and consequently the cart is reloaded, and a request is made, so the interceptor runs again. But, shouldn't CartService to be a singleton and it's constructor should run just once ?

Note: Both CartService and CartHttpService are with @Injectable({providedIn:'root'}) annotation

Code :

**CartService :**

```
export class CartService {


  private http: CartServiceHttp;

  constructor(http: CartServiceHttp,
              auth_service: AuthService) {
      auth_service.isLogged().subscribe( (is_logged: boolean) => this.loadCart());
  }

  loadCart() {

    this.http.getCart().pipe(

      tap( (resp) => {
        if (resp.hash) {
          localStorage.setItem('CH', resp.hash);
        }

        this.loaded_cart = true;
      }))

    .subscribe( (resp) => {
      this.cart_subject.next(new Cart(resp));
    });
  }
}
```

**CartHashInterceptor:**

```
@Injectable()
export class CartHashInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private cart_service: CartService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

   const hash = this.cart_service.getCartHash();

   request = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers.set('Cart-Hash', hash)
      });

   return next.handle(request);
}
```

**CartServiceHttp**

```
Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartServiceHttp {

  private http: HttpClient;

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
      this.http = http;
  }

  getCart(): Observable<Cart> {
    const url = environment.cart_url + '/cart';
    return this.http.get<Cart>(url)
                    .pipe(take(1));
  }
}
```

Comment: You cant have the carthashinterceptor import cartservice and also have the cartservice import cashimportinterceptor. This is called a circular dependency. You need to restructure your code better.

Comment: But Cartservice, is not importing the interceptor.

Comment: http: CartServiceHttp? Lets see your code for that CartServiceHttp

Comment: I added the CartServiceHttp code to the question.

Comment: you need make an "if" in your interceptor to avoid create a hash if your request is "getCartHash". Some like if (req.url!="enviroment.cart_url+"/cart" )...

Comment: Eliseo, i made some ifs, it didin't solve the problem

Comment: Show me where you are declaring/importing the CartService into a module please.

Comment: The CartService is declares into the app.module on providers array.

Comment: For interceptor concept your implementation is wrong... because interceptor intercepts every http request that's why it is going in infinite loop because to get hash again you are making a http request....Try to avoid that

Comment: Mukulsharma. The request is made um the constructor of the service. And since the service is a singleton, it shouldn't run the constructor more than once, no ?